# How to avoid redirecting user to homepage when there is an error while submitting the form using Redux Action in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I wanted to avoid redirecting user to homepage when there is an error while submitting the form during dispatching with redux action. Whenever we have error I am throwing one error message but not able to stop navigating towards the homepage. I am getting everything from store to stop redirecting user to homepage but it's not working. Can you please tell me what is going wrong with below code ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  addContactStart,
} from "../redux/contacts/contacts.actions";
import { MDBInput, MDBBtn, MDBTypography, MDBIcon } from "mdb-react-ui-kit";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: "auto",
    padding: "30px",
    maxWidth: "500px",
    alignContent: "center",
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "45ch",
    },
  },
}));

const initialState = {
  name: "",
  mobile: "",
  email: "",
};

const AddContact = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { contact, contacts, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.data
  );
  const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const [emptyErrorMsg, setEmptyErrorMsg] = useState("");

  let history = useHistory();
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { name, email, mobile } = state;

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };

  useEffect(() => error && toast.error(error), [error]);


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!name || !email || !mobile) {
      setEmptyErrorMsg("Please fill all input Field");
    } else {
        dispatch(addContactStart({ state, token }));
        if (!error) {
          history.push("/");
          setEmptyErrorMsg("");
        }
     }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {emptyErrorMsg && (
        <MDBTypography style={{ color: "red" }}>{emptyErrorMsg}</MDBTypography>
      )}
      <form
        className={classes.root}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <MDBInput
          label="Name"
          value={name || ""}
          name="name"
          type="text"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <MDBInput
          label="Email"
          name="email"
          value={email || ""}
          type="email"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <MDBInput
          label="Contact"
          value={mobile || ""}
          name="mobile"
          type="number"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
         
      
        <MDBBtn
          style={{ width: "100px" }}
          type="submit"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        >
          Submit
        </MDBBtn>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddContact;
```

Comment: try `dispatch(addContactStart({ state, token })).then(...redirectcode).catch(..handleerror)`

Comment: That is not working

Comment: So If I get it right the `if (!error) {` condition is not working? Can you check how the error value changes in time and if it is set properly and what is its value when you submit the form?

Comment: It is not working with this condition. I am getting error from server side actually. And storing error message in reducer state. There is no client side validation. So, handleSubmit condition don't work as well as if i try in useEffect() also didn't work out